# How to replace \" with empty value

Tags: java, json, replace, replaceall

I have a JSON string:

```
{
    "key1": "abc",
    "key2": "def",
    "key3": "gh\"i\"j"
}
```

Expected o/p:

```
{
    "key1": "abc",
    "key2": "def",
    "key3": "ghij"
}
```

Java string `replace()` and `replaceAll()` are replacing all double quotes:

```
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\\"",""));

System.out.println(a.replace("\"",""));
```

Output:

```
{
    key1: abc,
    key2: def,
    key3: ghij
}
```

The reason I'm trying to replace `\"` is that some operation has to be done using JSON, escaping special characters and storing the JSON string to a database. Here the json becomes invalid because of `\"`.

How can I replace only `\"` with empty value?

Comment: `replaceAll("\\\\\"", "")` works. But I am still trying to figure out why. It seems that you are "not escaping enough".

Comment: `\\\\ ` after string escaping is `\\ ` which is the regex escaping of `\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace `\"` with an empty string.

`\` has a special meaning in regular expressions so you need to escape it. Hence, you need to replace `\\"` with an empty string.

Then, writing the string `\\"` in a string in java requires to escape each `\` + the `"`.

Hence, the expression is `\\ \\ \"` (I added some spaces for readability):

Finally, you need to write it like this :

```
a.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm still wondering how `replaceAll("\\\"","")` replaced `\"` with empty.